# change the nickname of the user using id

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to change the nickname of the user using id. I tried to do it like this:

```
for (id in users) {
      message.guild.members.fetch(id).setNickname(users[id]["name"]) 
      .catch(error => { message.channel.send("ok"); })};
};
```

```
TypeError: message.guild.members.fetch(...).setNickname(users[id]["name"]) is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch returns a promise (as does setNickname which you are catching), so at the time you are calling setNickname, it hasn't finished yet.  You need to wait on it using async/await or .then.

```
message.guild.members.fetch(id).then(member => {
    member.setNickname(users[id]["name"])
        .catch(error => message.channel.send("ok"));
}).catch(error => message.channel.send('fetch error'));
```